# valgrind unhandled instruction bytes: 0xF 0xB 0xFF 0x85

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, x86, valgrind

I tried to run my program compiled with **Apple GCC 3.2.1** (forced 32-bit mode, x86 only) under **valgrind 3.6.1**, but I get the following error during initialization phase:

```
vex x86->IR: unhandled instruction bytes: 0xF 0xB 0xFF 0x85
==80746== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0x2a6c2a9.
==80746== Your program just tried to execute an instruction that Valgrind
==80746== did not recognise.  There are two possible reasons for this.
==80746== 1. Your program has a bug and erroneously jumped to a non-code
==80746==    location.  If you are running Memcheck and you just saw a
==80746==    warning about a bad jump, it's probably your program's fault.
==80746== 2. The instruction is legitimate but Valgrind doesn't handle it,
==80746==    i.e. it's Valgrind's fault.  If you think this is the case or
==80746==    you are not sure, please let us know and we'll try to fix it.
==80746== Either way, Valgrind will now raise a SIGILL signal which will
==80746== probably kill your program.
==80746== 
==80746== Process terminating with default action of signal 4 (SIGILL)
==80746==  Illegal opcode at address 0x2A6C2A9
```

Can you please tell me what is this instruction and what should I do? If I run my application under **gdb**, I pass this code area without a problem...

Comment: Can you compile with debug? Maybe it will give you some more info....  Especially resolving the address `0x2a6c2a9`

Comment: Is it only with this application or a general problem with valgrind on this system?

Comment: Yes, I'm running debug build of my application and this is the only application valgrind has troubles with...

Comment: So do you know what you are doing at that address.  I know in GDB you can get the source via address by doing `list *address`.  But that doesn't help too much because when running valgrind the program will be at a different position than when you run it again in gdb

Comment: add the debugger to valgrind by `--db-attach=yes` on the valgrind command, this will (hopefully) ask you to attach when that error occurs, then you can perform a `list *address` on the address that is given

Comment: Well, attaching a debugger caused a very gruesome message "valgrind: m_debugger.c:240 (ptrace_setregs): Assertion 'Unimplemented functionality' failed."
 :(

Comment: wow, very wierd.  Well back to the drawing board...Any idea what code of yours is causing the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The byte sequence `0xF 0xB` is the opcode `UD2`.

This is a defined "Undefined Instruction", if that makes any sense: there are many possible opcodes that are not legal, but this one is specifically reserved as an instruction which is guaranteed to raise a `#UD` invalid opcode exception, even on future processors.

There is one (and I can only think of one) vaguely plausible reason why it might be *deliberately* executed by code: the GCC built-in `__builtin_trap()` generates a `UD2` instruction on x86, and I've occasionally seen that used instead of `abort()` to cause a fatal error which will be caught by a debugger.

Comment: Man... Thanks, Matthew, I'll try to look into it, although I have no idea why gdb has no problems with it...

Comment: Damn it! I missed a warning 'Cannot pass objects of non-POD type...' :( Although, I still don't understand why gdb has no problems with non-POD types...

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I have no idea if this helps, but that looks to be an undefined instruction:</strike>

<strike>http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html#x0F0B</strike>

More like: http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html#xFB

Looks to be some low level interrupt management going on (for semaphores for example).  But usually this can only be done by privileged threads in kernel mode, so I wonder why that code can do it.

---

More likely I am incorrect about which instruction, but it would make sense that valgrind doesn't know much about the interrupt instruction in x86

Comment: Could this be debug break (int 3) or something like that?

Comment: Could it be the `STI` instruction (which requires IO priveleges)?

Comment: This has nothing to do with interrupts. This is for opcode ud2, which is _intentionally_ undefined

Comment: @Bob Heh, yeah, it would appear so :)

Comment: I didn't think that the undefined instruction would pop up, but I guess it is just one of those rare occurances